# Is memory-mapped memory possible?

Tags: c++, c, memory, compression, memory-mapped-files

I know that is possible to use memory-mapped files i.e. real files on disk that are transparently mapped to memory. As far as I understand (I haven't used these yet) the mapping takes place immediately, the file is partly read on the first memory access while the OS starts "caching" the whole file in the background.

Now: Is it possible to somewhat abuse this concept and memory-map another block of memory? Assuming the OS provides such indirection one could create a kind of `compressed_malloc()` that returns a mapping from memory to memory. The memory returned to the caller is simple the memory-mapped range that is transparently compressed in memory and also eventually kept in memory. Thus, for large buffers it could be possible that only part of it get decompressed on-the-fly (on access) while the remaining blocks are kept compressed.

Is that concept technically possible at the moment or - if already realized (in software) - what are the things to look at?

Update 1: I am more or less looking for something that is technically achievable without modifying the OS kernel itself or which requires a virtualization platform.

Update 2: I am hoping for something which allows me to implement the compression and related logic in my own user-space code. I would just use the facilities of the operating system to create the memory-mapping.

Comment: Many modern file systems support transparent compression (NTFS, ZFS, others). How that interacts with memory mapping, I'm not sure, but that could be what you're looking for.

Comment: No, I do not want to create a file. Not in any case. I want to keep the whole memory-mapped memory in memory (hence the name) and release it after use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very much so. The VM (Virtual Memory) system is designed to handle different kinds of objects that can be mapped. There is in fact a filesystem call [cramfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramfs) that does something similar in the sense that it keeps compressed data in storage, but enables transparent, uncompressed access.

You would not be modifying the kernel per se, but you will have to work in the kernel space, implementing VM handlers for this new kind of a memory mapped object.

Comment: Thanks, that looks quite interesting but (1) it seems to be read-only (it does not proof that writes are possible) and (2) it feels rather low-level. I was hoping for something, where I implement the compression and logic in my own user-space code and just use the facilities of the operating system to create the memory-mapping.

Comment: Right. Cramfs is not what you want. I just mentioned it because it uses the VM system for compressed content, similar to what you are talking about. I can't think of a way to do all this transparently in the user space. You would, at a minimum, need to write a driver and implement the mmap interface for it. But writing drivers is pretty standard stuff. Not the same as actually modifying the kernel.

Comment: Maybe I had a misconception: I though software like [boost::iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html) uses a generic facility to map X to a memory range. Maybe it is just the specific facility of the OS to map a _file_ to a memory range.

Comment: Right. They are using mmap underneath. But this is the user space part of the mmap mechanism. The driver for the filesystem already implements the kernel resident portion of the mmap mechanism, which allows the standard mapping of files to memory. To do something different, like you are proposing, one way would be to implement a new driver, with it's own mmap interface, that offers the semantics that you are after.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I guess, this got a lot clearer to me. Do you actually know such drivers except those like cramfs/squashfs?

Comment: I have written drivers which implement the mmap interface. There is plenty of help on the net. And this book is free http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/. See Chapter 15 for the mmap interface.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I think I know enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, eg.
http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.resourcemanagement.doc_41/managing_memory_resources/c_memory_compression.html

It is not correctly implemented in kernel space in Linux, but something like this could be implemented in user space.

Comment: Uff, ok. I did not explicitly know beforehand, but I was thinking of something less intrusive than modifiying the kernel itself.